# After resolving conflicts android studio not showing any file to commit

Tags: android, git

After resolving merge conflicts, when I saved last file it just took me back to android studio and when I go to git push it shows nothing. Also my branch name changed to merging release/xxx from release/xxx
I resolved all conflicts. What went wrong here ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Probably you took all the changes from the release, instead of your changes. So, as per the git, there is nothing changes in your code. That is why you are not able to push. However this may be one of the probability.

Comment: Yes, I just verified and found that all changes which I took was from release. Thanks for your hint